# GridViewColumnHeader doesn't appear

Tags: wpf, xaml, gridviewcolumn

I have a WPF form with some GridViewColumns in them to display the data. However, even though I set the Header property in each column, the headers never appear.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="MyProject.ViewModel.MyClassView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:MyProject.ViewModel"        
        Title="Title" Height="210.4" Width="500" ResizeMode="NoResize" 
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterOwner" WindowStyle="ToolWindow">
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="tempA">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=dataA}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="tempB">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=dataB}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="tempC">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=dataC}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="5,5,5,5">
        <ListView x:Name="MyList" ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataCollection}" MouseDoubleClick="ListView_MouseDoubleClick">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="colA" Header="Name" Width="100" CellTemplate="{StaticResource tempA}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="colB" Header="Type" Width="100" CellTemplate="{StaticResource tempB}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="colC" Header="Diameter" Width="100" CellTemplate="{StaticResource tempC}"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code-behind:

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModel
{
    public partial class MyClassView : Window
    {
        public object SelectedItem = null;

        public MyClassView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ListView_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            SelectedItem = MyList.SelectedItem;
        }
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace MyProject.ViewModel
{
    public class MyViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public object MyDataCollection { get; set; }

        public MyViewModel(object collection, string type)
        {
            Type = type;
            MyDataCollection = collection;
        }

        internal void RaisePropertyChanged(string prop)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) { PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop)); }
        }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
}
```

The object that is passed into the ViewModel constructor is guaranteed to contain dataA, dataB and dataC among others.

Could someone explain why the headers in my GridView aren't appearing?

Comment: For me column headers are displayed per your code. Can you give more details

Comment: There isn't really a lot more to this... This is a standalone window that is spawned as a child of another window. There's almost not code at all associated with it - just a constructor and some other variable definitions.

Comment: post all the code you have

Comment: Have you tried using a [DataGrid](https://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html)? That might be what you are looking for

Comment: @lightlike Thanks, using a DataGrid worked for me. It looks a little different from when I was using a regular Grid but that's fine, as long as the column headers are appearing.

Comment: @bemailloux I will add it as an answer so you can close the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a [DataGrid](https://wpftutorial.net/DataGrid.html) instead.

It would look something like this:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataCollection}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" >
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}" IsReadOnly="True"/>
        <DataGridComboBoxColumn Header="Type" ItemsSource="{Binding TypeList}" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Type}"/>
        ...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```